# Encode Mic Audio CMSamplebuffer to AAC

Tags: ios, audio, encoding, aac

I used the code found at the link below. It doesn't work with iPhone 5 as no audio is processed(while the mic are ok). For iPhone 6s the audio quality is good Only when the headphone is connected but without it the audio has a gap for like every other second.

https://github.com/chrisballinger/FFmpeg-iOS-Encoder/blob/master/FFmpegEncoder/AACEncoder.m

Can you suggest a better approach on encoding audio from the mic? I am sending the data to a server and writing to file is NOT an option unless it is fast and I can grab the AAC data with timestamps.